# How to suppress messages when opening multiple files with gvim -p file1 file2 file3

Tags: vim

When I open multiple files in tabs using gvim -p file1 file2 file3 ... I get an info line about each file at the bottom of my screen followed by "Press ENTER or type command to continue". Short of setting cmdheight to some very large value, how can I suppress all of this output and simply let gvim open the files with no further input from me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? Prompting for input for simply opening a file is not, as far as I'm aware, standard (g)vim behaviour.

Comment: If you have gvim, try opening several files with the -p option and you will see the messages and the prompt that I am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this in plain Vim. Probably, some plugin / customization is issuing messages on the `BufRead` event. One way to suppress this is by temporarily disabling autocmds during opening (though this may affect the plugins):

```
vim --cmd "set eventignore=all" -p *.txt -c "set eventignore="
```

You can try this also with other related options, e.g. `set [no]more`.

Comment: Thanks Ingo! That works fine. I wrapped gvim in a bat file (I'm on MS Windows) with these options and the messages/prompt are gone. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, glad my attempt was right! Please don't forget to accept the answer to mark your question closed.

Comment: Actually, I am checking out all the "eventignore" settings to see if I can narrow the impact, since 'all' option prevents syntax settings based on filetype, etc. It would be ideal to find a setting that only ignores events related to file opens.

Comment: That should be mostly `BufRead`, maybe `BufReadPre`, too.

Comment: It was BufReadPre, Ingo. Thanks again for your help. Also, being fairly new to StackOverflow, how to I accept the answer to mark my question as closed? Thanks.

Comment: Glad that worked! Just press the outlined checkmark next to my answer to accept it; it'll turn green, and you're done.